# jquery ajax file uploading not working var_dump($_FILES) gives empty array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form-data

i have tried to find a solution to my question in this website but i couldn't solve my problem.
it is html part:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit_profile_form" >
<input type="file" name="new_profile_photo" id="new_profile_photo" value="Choose Photo" >
<button class="button11" name="save_changes" id="button11" >SAVE </button>
</form>
```

this is ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '#button11', function(){ 
      event.preventDefault();

          var file_data = $("#new_profile_photo").prop('files')[0];
          var form_data = new FormData();
          form_data.append('file', file_data);

        $.ajax({  
                  url:"ajax/editprofile.php",  
                  method:"POST",  
                  async: false,
                  cache: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  processData: false,
                  data: form_data,

                  success:function(data){   
                      $("#error_messages").html(data);

                  }  
              });  


      });
</script>
```

when i write var_dump($_FILES) it gives me empty array. if anyone knows ho to solve it please help. thanks

Comment: use ajax can`t upload files.

Comment: if i will be able to get form_data i will upload files. i think

Comment: ajax work with flash(swf)  file can upload files. maybe jquery uploadify is what you need.

Comment: thanks i checked it out. it is really useful. but i just need to fix my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

JS

```
    $('#upload').on('click', function() {
            var file_data = $('#pic').prop('files')[0];
            var form_data = new FormData();
            form_data.append('file', file_data);

            $.ajax({
                    url         : 'upload.php',     // point to server-side PHP script 
                    dataType    : 'text',           // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                    cache       : false,
                    contentType : false,
                    processData : false,
                    data        : form_data,                         
                    type        : 'post',
                    success     : function(output){
                        alert(output);              // display response from the PHP script, if any
                    }
             });
             $('#pic').val('');                     /* Clear the file container */
        });
```

Php

```
    <?php
        if ( $_FILES['file']['error'] > 0 ){
            echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
        }
        else {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']))
            {
                echo "File Uploaded Successfully";
            }
        }

    ?>
```

It will upload the file to uploads directory

Comment: I am using the same code and it is working fine. Check if your file id is "pic" or not?

Comment: can you write me on facebook?  https://www.facebook.com/binnet.musayev94

Comment: the code is same. i can't figure out problem. i changed #pic to my id

Comment: worked. when i was trying to upload images i tried to upload image that is more than 3 mb. now i tried image with less data 1mb. it worked fine. thanks